# How can i swipe zoom in & zoom out in KendoUI Line Chart for iPhone Application?

Tags: iphone, ios5, kendo-ui

I want to use KendoUI Line chart for iPhone application.

Can anybody help me how to implement zoom in/out functionality?

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately panning and zooming is only available in the StockChart.  It isn't implemented in the other Chart types yet unfortunately...

http://www.kendoui.com/forums/dataviz/chart/how-to-pan-and-zoom.aspx